# How to pass a functional argument to the decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted, python-decorators

I am using decorator: **deferred_set_context** to set the function module, name and time as the context string(basically this context is needed to trace in-case there are multiple calls to **register_request**)

```
@deferred_set_context()    
def register_request(self, machine_model):

def deferred_set_context(name=None):
    def __outer__(func):
        context_name = name
        if not context_name:
            context_name = func.__name__

        @defer.inlineCallbacks
        def __inner__(*args, **kwargs):
            r = None
            with base.this_context_if_no_context(base.Context('%s.%s.%s' % (func.__module__, context_name,
                                                                         datetime.utcnow().strftime(
                                                                             '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')))):
                r = yield func(*args, **kwargs)
            defer.returnValue(r)

        return __inner__
    return __outer__
```

Now I need to set pass the **machine_model** name(which is argument of **register_request**) to this decorator: **register_request**. Something like this:

```
@deferred_set_context(name=machine_model)    
def register_request(self, machine_model):
```

How shall I do it?

Comment: `deferred_set_context` appears to take an argument `name` and returns a function called `__outer__`, but `name` does not appear to be a function, because it is never called, thus it is not a decorator. In fact I am not even sure where `func` comes from.

Comment: @Tommy `func` is the wrapped function, in this case `register_request`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the following two code snippets are equivalent

```
# first
@decorator
def func():
    pass

# second
def func():
    pass
func = decorator(func)
```

You need to make your decorator take a function as an argument. If you want to pass name in as a variable, then it should be a parameter in the function returned by the decorator.

Comment: I was under the impression that a decorator is a python function that returns a function. Meaning, that it *must* take a function as an argument (as wel as return a function) to be a decorator.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to change the behavior of `deferred_set_context` or `register_request`, you could make a second shim decorator that spies on the correct function argument and passes it along to your original decorator.

Something like this:

```
def new_shim_decorator(register_request):
    def wrapper(self, machine_model):
        return deferred_set_context(machine_model)(self, machine_model)
    return wrapper

@new_shim_decorator
def register_request(self, machine_model):
    print("my_function called with {}".format(machine_model))
```

This is kind of a hacky solution in my opinion since this decorator that proxies to the original decorator would need to know the arguments passed to `register_request` and mirror them.

I would prefer to see a keyword-only argument that get be optionally `get`-ed from the keyword argument dictionary in either a shim decorator or the original:

```
def deferred_set_context_by_kwarg(kwarg_name):
    def outer(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return deferred_set_context(name=kwargs.get(kwarg_name))(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return outer

@deferred_set_context_by_kwarg('machine_model')
def register_request(self, *, machine_model):
    print("my_function called with {}".format(machine_model))
```

Notice the `*, machine_model`.  That `*` is a Python 3 feature that requires `machine_model` to be specified as a keyword argument.  This allows our `deferred_set_context_by_kwarg` decorator to accept a string representing the name of the keyword argument we want and use that name to retrieve the keyword argument value and pass to `deferred_set_context` upon each function call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your function `register_request` takes always the same 2 arguments then pick them inside the decorator code.